# C#: Compiler optimization, function calls, and Boolean expression short-circuiting

Tags: c#, optimization, short-circuiting, boolean-operations

Let's assume that we have the following expensive functions:

```
bool ExpensiveOp1() { ... }
bool ExpensiveOp2() { ... }
bool ExpensiveOp3() { ... }
```

Also, to keep it simple, assume that none of them have side effects.

I know that C# can short-circuit if `ExpensiveOp1` or `ExpensiveOp2` returns `false` in the following expression:

```
return ExpensiveOp1() && ExpensiveOp2() && ExpensiveOp3();
```

However, is the compiler smart enough to (for lack of a better term) inline the function calls and take advantage of short-circuiting if I write the code this way?

```
var x = ExpensiveOp1();
var y = ExpensiveOp2();
var z = ExpensiveOp3();
return x && y && z;
```

Comment: you can go `var x = ExpensiveOp1; var y = ExpensiveOp2; var z = ExpensiveOp3; return x() && y() && z();` if you really can be bothered.

Comment: Thanks, @JohanP. I'll probably end up doing something like that with local functions. I boiled down my example to eliminate irrelevant details. I actually have the results of long Boolean expressions assigned to `x`, `y`, and `z`. I can encapsulate them in short-named local functions and put them in the `return` statement.

Comment: Beware of prioritizing micro-optimizations...

Comment: @Abion47, acknowledged and agreed. Just curious in case it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, and for a good reason.  The compiler doesn't know if any of your operations have side effects, so if you run them outside of a boolean short circuiting situation it runs them in case there are side effects you want.

Comment: That's what I suspected (was afraid of?), but I had trouble confirming it one way or the other as I looked around online. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Comment: @BradCollins You can test it yourself pretty easily. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/nunVOV

Comment: Compiler doesn't know anything about side effects and shouldn't care about it

Comment: @SergeyProsin With C# 8 they are adding more functional programming style compiler hints, and one of those is the ability to mark a function as "pure" (i.e., has no side effects) because there are situations where it is nice to know a function can be ignored.

Comment: @Abion47, thanks for the .NET Fiddle link! It demonstrates exactly what Turksarama says above. Now we have it documented on Stack Overflow and in a running code snippet. Thanks again.

Comment: @Turksarama Is there anywhere that it talks about that functionality? I can't find anywhere that mentions anything like that. The closest I can find is a [`Pure` attribute](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/functional-csharp-pure-function) that is used for .NET Code Contracts and seems largely arbitrary outside that usage.

Comment: @Abion47 Perhaps I got overexcited thinking about possibilities, it may just be a code contracts thing.

Comment: If those methods truly have zero side effects and live inside the same code being compiled, I would wager the compiler is going to optimize it clear down to a constant. A method that truly has ZERO side effects (not even output) is a constant.

Comment: @dodexahedron `(a, b) => a + b` has no side effects but definitely isn't constant (unless a and b are also both constant).

Comment: Sure it is. It's a void. The compiler would optimize it away to nothing at all, assuming those are primitive type inputs.

Comment: A single line lambda returns the result of the operation without the return keyword, so it isn't a void, it returns a + b.